# Loop through and sum multiple JSON values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through the below JSON data, extract the `total_price` field, sum it, then add the `amount` field, found in `refunds[<i>].transactions` array. As mentioned below I'm able to grab the `total_price` fields and sum, however am lost on how to also grab and sum the **refund** `amount` fields, which will be used to subtract from the `total_price` sum.

**JSON:**

```
{
"sales_mtd": {
"orders": [
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:30:47-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1099",
"refunds": [
{
"admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Refund/800483278870",
"created_at": "2021-06-25T19:18:05-04:00",
"duties": [],
"id": 800483278870,
"note": "",
"order_adjustments": [],
"order_id": 4071975550998,
"processed_at": "2021-06-25T19:18:05-04:00",
"refund_line_items": [],
"restock": true,
"total_duties_set": {
"presentment_money": {
"amount": "0.00",
"currency_code": "CAD"
},
"shop_money": {
"amount": "0.00",
"currency_code": "CAD"
}
},
"transactions": [
{
"admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/OrderTransaction/5016768315414",
"amount": "75.71",
"authorization": null,
"created_at": "2021-06-25T19:18:05-04:00",
"currency": "CAD",
"device_id": null,
"error_code": null,
"gateway": "manual",
"id": 5016768315414,
"kind": "refund",
"location_id": null,
"message": "Refunded 75.71 from manual gateway",
"order_id": 4071975550998,
"parent_id": 5015934074902,
"processed_at": "2021-06-25T19:18:05-04:00",
"receipt": {},
"source_name": "1830279",
"status": "success",
"test": false,
"user_id": 64086245398
}
],
"user_id": 64086245398
}
],
"total_price": "75.71"
},
```

I used this code to loop through the `total_price` fields and sum them, thanks to help in another question.

```
let sumReduce = json.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.total_price), 0);
console.log(sumReduce);
```

However, when I try and repurpose this to also grab and sum the **refund** amounts, I either get `NaN` or an error message unable to read the **transaction** or other field. I have tried reviewing MDN docs, starting from a less complex object, repurposing other answers but can't quite seem to get it. Any input is very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you post the code you tried that gave you this error? In the code you posted here I don't see any `transaction` field in the `json` object

Comment: @Snirka sorry wrong json, added the correct one

Comment: What field are you trying to sum? There is no `transaction` field you have `transactions`, `balance_transaction`, `network_transaction_id` and more.

Comment: Trying to sum the "amount" field, found under "transactions", which is part of the refunds array

Comment: Did the below answer solved your problem?

Comment: @Snirka Yes it did, thanks so much! Really helped unblock things to move to next part of what I'm working on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let sumReduce1 =  json.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((acc, order) => {
  if(order.refunds.length !== 0) {
    return acc + Number(order.refunds[0].transactions[0].amount);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, 0);

let sumReduce2 =  json.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((acc, order) => {
  if(order.refunds.length !== 0) {
    return order.refunds.reduce((acc1, refund) => {
      return refund.transactions.reduce((acc2, transaction) => acc2 + Number(transaction.amount), acc1);
    }, acc);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, 0);
```

`sumReduce1` and `sumReduce2` do the same thing for the JSON object you provide only that `sumReduce2` take into consideration that you can have multiple orders, refunds and transactions. `sumReduce1` is more of a hard coded function, I would advise using `sumReduce2`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me "transactions" is only available within the refunds array, and sometimes it is empty.

something like `if(refunds.length)` will do the job